# What is the correct FTP response to mode selection

Tags: server, ftp

I using the FubarDevelop FTPServer (https://github.com/FubarDevelopment/FtpServer/) in combination with a network device, that is capable to transfer automatically files to a FTP server. But the Fubar-FTP response with code 220 to the mode selection. But the description i found (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt at page 39 or page 51) says it should be code 200.

So my question: Is this a bug in the Fubar-FTP server or did I misunderstod something?

(I also made a issue there, but nobody answer to it :( )

Comment: Looks like a bug to me, but it also looks like you'll just have to cope with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Right now i use a modified copy. But i don't really like this solution, because of the lag of maintenance or the "bigger" workload to merge new versions into my copy. 
However, it works with my network device so far.